# Finding word association strengths from an input text

Tags: python, performance, python-3.x, natural-language-processing, data-mining

I have the written the following (crude) code to find the association strengths among the words in a given piece of text.

```
import re

## The first paragraph of Wikipedia's article on itself - you can try with other pieces of text with preferably more words (to produce more meaningful word pairs)
text = "Wikipedia was launched on January 15, 2001, by Jimmy Wales and Larry Sanger.[10] Sanger coined its name,[11][12] as a portmanteau of wiki[notes 3] and 'encyclopedia'. Initially an English-language encyclopedia, versions in other languages were quickly developed. With 5,748,461 articles,[notes 4] the English Wikipedia is the largest of the more than 290 Wikipedia encyclopedias. Overall, Wikipedia comprises more than 40 million articles in 301 different languages[14] and by February 2014 it had reached 18 billion page views and nearly 500 million unique visitors per month.[15] In 2005, Nature published a peer review comparing 42 science articles from Encyclopadia Britannica and Wikipedia and found that Wikipedia's level of accuracy approached that of Britannica.[16] Time magazine stated that the open-door policy of allowing anyone to edit had made Wikipedia the biggest and possibly the best encyclopedia in the world and it was testament to the vision of Jimmy Wales.[17] Wikipedia has been criticized for exhibiting systemic bias, for presenting a mixture of 'truths, half truths, and some falsehoods',[18] and for being subject to manipulation and spin in controversial topics.[19] In 2017, Facebook announced that it would help readers detect fake news by suitable links to Wikipedia articles. YouTube announced a similar plan in 2018."
text = re.sub("[\[].*?[\]]", "", text)     ## Remove brackets and anything inside it.
text=re.sub(r"[^a-zA-Z0-9.]+", ' ', text)  ## Remove special characters except spaces and dots
text=str(text).lower()                     ## Convert everything to lowercase
## Can add other preprocessing steps, depending on the input text, if needed.







from nltk.corpus import stopwords
import nltk

stop_words = stopwords.words('english')

desirable_tags = ['NN'] # We want only nouns - can also add 'NNP', 'NNS', 'NNPS' if needed, depending on the results

word_list = []

for sent in text.split('.'):
    for word in sent.split():
        '''
        Extract the unique, non-stopword nouns only
        '''
        if word not in word_list and word not in stop_words and nltk.pos_tag([word])[0][1] in desirable_tags:
            word_list.append(word)





'''
Construct the association matrix, where we count 2 words as being associated 
if they appear in the same sentence.

Later, I'm going to define associations more properly by introducing a 
window size (say, if 2 words seperated by at most 5 words in a sentence, 
then we consider them to be associated)
'''

import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

table = np.zeros((len(word_list),len(word_list)), dtype=int)

for sent in text.split('.'):
    for i in range(len(word_list)):
        for j in range(len(word_list)):
            if word_list[i] in sent and word_list[j] in sent:
                table[i,j]+=1

df = pd.DataFrame(table, columns=word_list, index=word_list)







# Count the number of occurrences of each word in word_list

all_words = pd.DataFrame(np.zeros((len(df), 2)), columns=['Word', 'Count'])
all_words.Word = df.index

for sent in text.split('.'):
    count=0
    for word in sent.split():
        if word in word_list:
            all_words.loc[all_words.Word==word,'Count'] += 1







# Sort the word pairs in decreasing order of their association strengths

df.values[np.triu_indices_from(df, 0)] = 0 # Make the upper triangle values 0

assoc_df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Word 1', 'Word 2', 'Association Strength (Word 1 -> Word 2)'])
for row_word in df:
    for col_word in df:
        '''
        If Word1 occurs 10 times in the text, and Word1 & Word2 occur in the same sentence 3 times,
        the association strength of Word1 and Word2 is 3/10 - Please correct me if this is wrong.
        '''
        assoc_df = assoc_df.append({'Word 1': row_word, 'Word 2': col_word, 
                                        'Association Strength (Word 1 -> Word 2)': df[row_word][col_word]/all_words[all_words.Word==row_word]['Count'].values[0]}, ignore_index=True)

assoc_df.sort_values(by='Association Strength (Word 1 -> Word 2)', ascending=False)
```

This produces the word associations like so:

```
        Word 1          Word 2          Association Strength (Word 1 -> Word 2)
330     wiki            encyclopedia    3.0
895     encyclopadia    found           1.0
1317    anyone          edit            1.0
754     peer            science         1.0
755     peer            encyclopadia    1.0
756     peer            britannica      1.0
...
...
...
```

However, the code contains a lot of `for` loops which hampers its running time. Specially the last part (`sort the word pairs in decreasing order of their association strengths`) consumes a lot of time as it computes the association strengths of `n^2` word pairs/combinations, where `n` is the number of words we are interested in (those in `word_list` in my code above).

So, the following are what I would like some help on:

1. How do I vectorize the code, or otherwise make it more efficient?
2. Instead of producing `n^2` combinations/pairs of words in the last step, is there any way to prune some of them before producing them? I am going to prune some of the useless/meaningless pairs by inspection after they are produced anyway.
3. Also, and I know this does not really fall into the purview of code review, but I would love to know if there's any mistake in my logic, specially when calculating the word association strengths.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Review

- Styling

1. Import should be at the top of the file
2. Use a `if __name__ == '__main__':` guard
3. Split some functionality into function, keeping everything in the global namespace is considered bad form

- Use [`str.translate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.translate) for cleaning texts

This should faster compared to regex substitution

Secondly you can use `string.punctuation` which in is in the standard library, making your first code block:

```
    trans_table = str.maketrans('', '', string.punctuation.replace('.', ''))
    trans_text = text.translate(trans_table).lower()
```

*You'd still need to clean the wiki references `[15]...etc` from the text though*

- Why do you import nltk 2 times?

Just `import nltk` once

- Using `set` lookup is O(0)

Instead of checking if a variable is in a list you should compare against a set, this will improve performance, [see Python time complexity](https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity)

```
    stop_words = set(nltk.corpus.stopwords.words('english'))
```

- Use list comprehension

List comprehension should be a bit faster compared to appending in a for loop, and it is considered Pythonic,

Secondly you can pre-process the text to hold a list of sentences, instead of calculating it everytime

```
    word_list = set(
        word for sent in trans_text.split('.') for word in sent.split() 
        if word not in stop_words and nltk.pos_tag([word])[0][1] in desirable_tags
    )
    sentences = [
        set(sentence.split()) for sentence in trans_text.split('.')
    ]
```

- Use [enumerate](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0279/) if you need both the item and the index

  ```
    table = np.zeros((len(word_list), len(word_list)), dtype=int)
    for sent in sentences:
        for i, e in enumerate(word_list):
            for j, f in enumerate(word_list):
                if e in sent and f in sent:
                    table[i,j] += 1
  ```
- Use [`collections.Counter()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) for counting words

And you can create a dataframe from `Counter` in one go with

```
    count_words = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(Counter(word_list), orient='index').reset_index()
```

But you don't need to convert it to a dataframe at all, since you can get the word count by just reading the Dictionary

```
    count_words = Counter(word_list)
    ...
    assoc_df = assoc_df.append({'Word 1': row_word, 
                                'Word 2': col_word, 
                                'Association Strength (Word 1 -> Word 2)': df[row_word][col_word]/count_words[row_word]}, 
                                ignore_index=True)
```

*Note that I am not really into Pandas/Preprocessing so I might have missed a few things :)*

Comment: I'll definitely try these suggestions. The biggest problem seems be in the last segment - all the other code blocks finish within a minute or two each, at max. But the last segment for calculating word pair association strengths, with a different piece of input text that produces 800 odd words in `word_list`, is going on running for the last 2 hours. So, that's the more urgent part.

Comment: I might take another stab at it when I have some time again. Or maybe someone else will pick that up.

Comment: *"Using set lookup is O(0)"* You mean O(1).